# Как реализовать отображение рекламы fullscreen (interstitial) от admob?

Tags: android, unity3d, admob

Здравствуйте.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать отображение рекламы fullscreen (interstitial) от admob в Unity3D. С английским у меня туговато, но буду очень рад, если вы поделитесь ссылкой. Если от admob ничего нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть альтернативы.

Comment: @Welgum, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу найти плагин для admob. А если его нет, то у каких рекламодателей есть?

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial

переводите переводчиком слова которые не знаете.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте Appodeal. У них есть документация на русском и доступ ко всем крупнейшим сетям, включая AdMob:

http://www.appodeal.ru/docs/choose_framework

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения.